# Combine multiple vectors into same element of a new vector?

Tags: r, vector

I wish to combine multiple vectors into one vector; however, I do not wish to simply concatenate them together. I want them to merge for the same elements as such:

```
vector1 <- c(1, 2, 3)
vector2 <- c("a", "b", "c")
```

vector1 and vector2 combined would return:

```
vector3 <- c("1a", "2b", "2c")
```

And not:

```
vector3 <- c(1, 2, 3, "a", "b", "c")
```

This result is the only information I can find online, but is not what I want.

Comment: `paste0(vector1, vector2)`  BTW, in your expected, it is `d` instead of `b`

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, thank you!. Not sure how I had not come across this in my search process.